# Breaking from nested try/except blocks in python

Tags: python, try-except

The following code has two try/except blocks. If the inner code fails it raises an exception but still continues the next code after that. Is it possible to break from all block as soon as one enters the except block?

```
try:
    try:
        print(a)
    except:
        print('Inner')
        # should break from here and exit the script
    print(k)
except Exception as e:
    print('Outer')
```

The above code prints `Inner` but throws an exception for not defining `k` as well. The `Outer` shouldn't be printed as well.

Comment: it prints inner outer, whaat is your point?

Comment: @E.Serra Added a comment

Comment: I'm not really sure what you  want to do. Assuming you want to jump to the outer except block, you could simply write "raise Exception" in the inner except

Comment: @CanciuCostin It shouldn't come to the outer block

Comment: Does putting `exit(0)` after the `print('Inner')` line work as you'd like it to?

Comment: *should break from here and exit the script* - then just do `sys.exit()`

Comment: placing exit(0) does not exit both blocks... I'm facing the same issue. Did you manage to resolve @noswear?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're after the `try`...`except` with the optional `else` clause included:

```
try:
    try:
        print(a)
    except:
        print('Inner')
    else:
        print(k)
except Exception as e:
    print('Outer')
```

Which will print `Inner` if `a` is not defined, and will print `Outer` if `a` is defined

Answer (score 0):

This will avoid printing outter exception ->

```py
try:
    try:
        print(a)
    except:
        print('Inner')
    try:
        print(k)
    except:
        print('Inner for k')
except Exception as e:
    print('Outer')
```

You can use a function to avoid the remaining commands

```py
def printvars():
    try:
        try:
            print(a)
        except:
            print('Inner')
            return 
        try:
            print(k)
        except:
            print('Inner for k')
    except Exception as e:
        print('Outer')
```

I would avoid using catch-all exceptions, this can lead to a lot of unexpected results.